# Full calendar date not update after drag event to another day.

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using jquery full calendar version 2.2. My event has `editable : true` property. But If I dragged it to another day, event's start date or end date does not update. Why is that? Are there any property to do it?

Comment: Hey GRTZ, can you please provide some code of your configuration or make a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/)?